# checking email with python 3.6 instead 2.7

Tags: python, email

i am interesting into make a python script that would automatically check emails. i've found similar post on stackoverflow but it is outdated (it's from 2009) and it's not working.
i need help to try to make something similar to this

```
import poplib
from email import parser

pop_conn = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.gmail.com')
pop_conn.user('username')
pop_conn.pass_('password')
#Get messages from server:
messages = [pop_conn.retr(i) for i in range(1, len(pop_conn.list()
[1]) + 1)]
# Concat message pieces:
messages = ["\n".join(mssg[1]) for mssg in messages]
#Parse message intom an email object:
messages = [parser.Parser().parsestr(mssg) for mssg in messages]
for message in messages:
print message['subject']
pop_conn.quit()
```

i am working on a 3.6 python this code is from 2.7, there is any way to convert this and make it works?

Comment: Earn some reputation and then offer a **[bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)** on the old question for a solution that works with 3.6. No point in asking a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 2to3 tool to convert old source code to newer Python versions: https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html

Comment: File "/Users/nicolas/Documents/EMAIL ARRIVO.py", line 6, in <module>
    pop_conn.pass_('AT1555932')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/poplib.py", line 197, in pass_
    return self._shortcmd('PASS %s' % pswd)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/poplib.py", line 160, in _shortcmd
    return self._getresp()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/poplib.py", line 136, in _getresp
    raise error_proto(resp)   This is what i get

Comment: Did you try using the 2to3 tool?